# Understandable word for someone with normal vision

Tags: phrase-requests

In the process of writing a document relating to an accessibility product I mention people who are blind and people who are visually impaired.

However I cannot think of a good word with the average reader will immediately understand and does not sound too clinical for a person with an good level of sight (not necessarily perfect as 20/20 would suggest but just fine for everyday life).

For example the sentence: "The product has been trialled on a selection of blind, visually impaired and _____ persons."

I considered "sighted" or "fully sighted" or even "seeing" however I fear each of those words might have implications. All of these seem to be fine according various dictionaries but I fear an average reader would find them odd and I have never personally seem them used in a sentence save in phrases like "short sighted".

Are there any other words that would work for this? Or perhaps the ones I have already thought of sound less out of place than I suspect they do?

Comment: Variations of "sighted" (eg, [normally sighted](https://books.google.com/books?id=jeLd0aHdrMAC&pg=PA72&dq=%22normally+sighted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR24KXt9rKAhXmzoMKHXQ5CKkQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=%22normally%20sighted%22&f=false)) are commonly used to describe someone without a severe vision difficulty.

Comment: @HotLicks If you think most readers would understand "normally sighted" to mean that I would certainly say that is an answer.

Comment: Any term you pick will depend to a degree on the context for comprehension.  Eg, popping the phrase "normally sighted" in the middle of a story on whale watching will cause confusion unless some consideration is given to the immediate context.

Comment: I concur with @HotLicks, but note that in one of our circles of friends, in which about half of the members are blind, the term "sighted" is preferred.  In this particular group, at least, adding "normally" would be a gaffe. Members would think it rude to imply that people who cannot see are not otherwise "normal."

Comment: If concerns such as Rob cites make you leery of "normally sighted", Ngram shows "fully sighted" to be about half as popular -- still reasonably well-known and understood.

Comment: @Rob_Ster That is interesting feedback. The last thing I would want to do would be to offend those with impaired vision - the group who we are attempting to most assist with the product. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: @HotLicks That is very good to know. It is important for me to balance the term being polite and neutral with being well understood by the audience. I am hoping that given in the context of already writing about visual impairments people should hopefully at least guess at the meaning of either phrase  even if it appears unfamiliar. Also, thank you for mentioning Ngram, I had not thought of using that to assess potential familiarity of the phrases.

Comment: You of course do have to be careful with Ngram, in that you can get all sorts of false readings.  But for this sort of thing it's quite useful.

Comment: You could just say "the blind, visually impaired and unimpaired."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***clearsighted/clear-sighted***

From **collinsdictionary.com**:

> [**clearsighted**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clearsighted)
>
> *adjective*
>   1.  **seeing clearly**
>
> [**clear-sighted**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clear-sighted)
>
> *adjective*
>   2. having clear vision
>
> She had regained her composure and her straight, clear-sighted gaze.

From **wiktionary**:

> *Adjective* **[clear-sighted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clear-sighted#English)** ‎(comparative more clear-sighted, superlative most clear-sighted)
>
> Having sharp vision.